# Is there a known trivia behind the wording used for XML declaration for XUL documents

Tags: xul

Why does it say `/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul`? Who picked this strange wording and why?

P.S. Some good tags for the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xul is a character from the first Ghostbusters film, and it does utter the phrase "There Is Only Zuul" (Zuul sounds like Xul). The keymaster and gatekeeper are other characters from the same film.

Even [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL#The_name) knows this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but found the `even` in your remark a bit hard to swallow :(

Comment: I believe it's "There is only Zuul", but it's pronounced the same.

Comment: @Majid - Googling "there.is.only.xul" should have been the first thing you did. Stackoverflow does not replace basic search skills.

Comment: That is the first thing I did, although I added the word *trivia* to my keywords, which should have offset the results. Besides, I do not care much about what some people *define* SO *is* or *isn't*. For me it has elements of a community and I enjoy asking questions here - well apparently you enjoy answering them too.

Answer (score 1):

```
If there's something strange
In your source code
Where you gonna post?

Stack Overflow!

If there's something weird
With that DOM node
Who you gonna call?

Stack Overflow!

We ain't afraid of no bug ...
```

Comment: +1 Could be kind of fun if someone made a youtube song with this as (part of) the lyrics. There is one for digg:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLLRsn_nr6s.